# Exception on stop when using ActorSystem and Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, akka, guice, playframework-2.3

I'm trying to remove some hardcoded dependencies in a Play 2.3.x app and use Guice instead to inject those dependencies. One of those is the Akka ActorSystem, for what I created a provider like this:

```
public static class ActorSystemProvider implements Provider<ActorSystem> {
    @Override public ActorSystem get() {
        return Akka.system();
    }
}
```

The problem is that when my Play app is closed (either by Ctrl-C or kill), I get an exception like this, and the app gets locked (only a force kill will terminate it):

```
Caused by: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error in custom provider, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't get ClosableLazy value after it has been closed
  while locating guice.Providers$ActorSystemProvider
  while locating akka.actor.ActorSystem
    for parameter 0 at some.Class.<init>(...)
  while locating some.Class
```

So it seems there are classes being initialized by Guice after the actor system was closed. The only way to get around this was using a try/catch and a mocked ActorSystem:

```
@Override public ActorSystem get() {
    ActorSystem sys;
    try {
        sys = Akka.system();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        sys = MOCKED_AS;
    }
    return sys;
}
```

but it seems a bit ugly. There is a better way to either provide the ActorSystem through Guice or to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

This is such a wierd problem. Me and my company are currently evaluating JPPF and AKKA and we're already on guice, so I suspect that I will be running into this problem soon.

My first question is: have you tried to find out *why* your code is requesting an akka instance when it shuts down? Can you squelch the problem at the source?

If not, is your life cycle one where there is only ever one instance of an ActorSystem? If so you can tell guice to bind it as a singleton, such that guice will cache the instance for you.

```java
class YourModule extends Module{

    @Override public void configure(){
        //...
        bind(ActorSystem.class).toInstance(Akka.system());

        //or, similarly
        bind(ActorSystem.class).asEagerSingleton(); //assumes you've told this injector instance how to get the ActorSystem somewhere else
    }

}
```

Assuming you cant (and I think its reasonable that as part of a shutdown hook somebody wants the current system), you might be able to solve this with some explicit provider methods.

```java
class YourModule extends Module{

    // configure...

    private ActorSystem mostRecentAkkaSystem;

    @Provides
    public ActorSystem getCurrentActorSystem(){

        try{
            mostRecentAkkaSystem = Akka.system();
        catch(IllegalStateException e){
            //do nothing, use cached value
        }

        return mostRecentAkkaSystem;

        //you're also welcome to use an if-else instead of try-catch here,
        //if you can find something akin to System.isShuttingDown(),
        //but after 5 minutes of googling, I couldn't, and you get a race condition 
        //if you add your own shutdown hook to do that manually
    }
}
```

If you're looking for a solution that boils down to something other than the rather barbaric 'cache the damn thing', I don't think I can help you much. You might consider reporting this as a bug to the Akka guys because at the absolute very least they should put a try-catch around their static methods to throw something like `new IllegalStateException("A system cannot be provided while the JVM is shutting down")` rather than throwing you an IllegalStateException that wraps some weird lazy-runtime exception.

Hope that helps!